# spring mvc @ModelAttribute and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring mvc application.
I am trying to use `@ModelAttribute` on Ajax call.

```
function setCountryCode() {
        var selectedCountry = $('select#country option:selected').val();

        $('#contactNoCode').val('');
        var updateUserFormModel = $("#updateUserForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}' + '/welcomeAjax/selectedCountry',
            data:updateUserFormModel,
            contentType: "application/json",-//here confused
            dataType : "application/json",//here confused
            success : function(response) {

                //what to do here

            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/selectedCountry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    <what to return here> selectedCountry(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserDetailsDto userDetailsDto,BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {

        //setters for userDetailsDto        
        return <what to return here>;
    }
```

On drop down `onchange()`, I am doing the ajax call.
On `userDetailsDto` I am getting all the form data, and will set different fields.
Now help me how to set userDetailsDto data to jsp form.

Alternatively, I can use json, text etc.

```
var selectedCountry = $('select#country option:selected').val();

String selectedCountry = request.getParameter("selectedCountry");
```

And

```
success : function(response) {

$('#contactNoCode').val(response);
```

But I am trying to avoid these `request.getParameter` and `).val(response)`

Not sure if it is possible or not, set form data with @ModelAttribute by ajax call.
Please help me.

Manu

Comment: You can achieve this in one way fashion, you can either submit DTO using model attribute or take as response using `@ResponseBody`. If you want spring to populate DTO in view then the only option is to use it in spring manner `Model + View (template) = HTML`

Comment: How ever you can provide whole `Model + View (template) = HTML` as response & then replace whole html in ajax success. `application/json` is not required in any case.